# Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, xcode9

I had published the app adding here the  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKf1D.png (in may case it called App Store icon http://prntscr.com/gu38j9) Missing Marketing, using xcode9, but apple store answered "Missing Marketing Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format". 
In Contents.json include:

```
{
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
      "filename" : "iTunesArtwork@2x.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
```

May be some one has idea what's wrong?

Comment: Why would you name a 1x image with the @2x suffix?

Comment: @rmaddy it has generated by xcode. I am not adding manual.

Comment: What version did you use for archiving? Archive and upload using same version of Xcode, i.e., using same version of XCode 9.

Comment: Thanks all, I deleted build and upload the same build again, and now every think good.